# object not found in R defined function

Tags: r, flextable

I have a script that creates a data set and creates a flextable object, highlighting specific cells

```
library(flextable)
library(tidyverse)
red_exlusion = '#FCE4D6'
green_include = '#E2EFDA'
df=data.frame(expand.grid(c(NA,1),c(NA,1),c(NA,1),c(NA,1)))
colnames(df) = paste0("col",1:4)
df$name = 1000:(1000+nrow(df)-1)
df = df %>%
  filter(!if_all(2:4, ~.x == 0))
red = ifelse(is.na(df),1,0)
green = data.frame()
for(n in 1:(ncol(red)-1)){
  r=ifelse(red[,n]==1 & red[,n+1] == 0,1,0)
  green = rbind(green, r)
}
green = t(green)
ft = df[,c(5,2:4)] %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,2]==1, j = 2,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,3]==1, j = 3,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,4]==1, j = 4,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,1]==1,j = 2, bg=green_include) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,2]==1,j = 3, bg=green_include) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,3]==1,j = 4, bg=green_include)
ft
```

[image]

but, when I enclose it in a function:

```
rm(list=ls())
test = function(){
red_exlusion = '#FCE4D6'
green_include = '#E2EFDA'
df=data.frame(expand.grid(c(NA,1),c(NA,1),c(NA,1),c(NA,1)))
colnames(df) = paste0("col",1:4)
df$name = 1000:(1000+nrow(df)-1)
df = df %>%
  filter(!if_all(2:4, ~.x == 0))
red = ifelse(is.na(df),1,0)
green = data.frame()
for(n in 1:(ncol(red)-1)){
  r=ifelse(red[,n]==1 & red[,n+1] == 0,1,0)
  green = rbind(green, r)
}
green = t(green)
ft = df[,c(5,2:4)] %>% 
  flextable() %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,2]==1, j = 2,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,3]==1, j = 3,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ red[,4]==1, j = 4,bg=red_exlusion) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,1]==1,j = 2, bg=green_include) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,2]==1,j = 3, bg=green_include) %>%
  bg(i = ~ green[,3]==1,j = 4, bg=green_include)
ft  
}
test()
```

I get `Error in eval(as.call(f[[2]]), envir = data) : object 'red' not found`

this corresponds to the flextable function `bg()` not being able to find the object `red` defined a few lines prior to the creation of the flextable object.

Here is the error traceback:

```
7.
eval(as.call(f[[2]]), envir = data)
6.
eval(as.call(f[[2]]), envir = data)
5.
get_i_from_formula(i, x$dataset)
4.
get_rows_id(x[[part]], i)
3.
bg(., i = ~red[, 2] == 1, j = 2, bg = red_exlusion)
2.
df[, c(5, 2:4)] %>% flextable() %>% bg(i = ~red[, 2] == 1, j = 2, 
bg = red_exlusion)
1.
test()
```

Is there a way to work around this so that the function can run accordingly?

Comment: Do you need the function to return an object and not print the object? Because you should kind of work the same if you just `print()` the object in the function where all the variables are defined.

Comment: The problem is the `~` in the call to `bg()`.  If you replace  `= ~ ` with just `=` in all of the `bg()` functions, it should work.